# Making background screen transparent react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react native navigation Bottom tabs navigator and are trying to make it so that when a component is null or has no opacity the background is the previously loaded in screen. However whenever a null component is passed in, the screen is white regardless of the view hierarchy.

```
  sceneContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
  detachInactiveScreens={false}
```

I tried these two parameters but to no avail. I can change the background color but it wont be transparent and show the previous screen.